# SharePoint Purchase Order

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, custom-list, data-view-web-part, dashboard-designer-2013

I want to develop small purchase order system in SharePoint. I already started working on this but I stuck in below points where the purchased Qty is coming on different dates. For example :-

Order Qty = 100, Purchased Qty (Qty delivered more than one time in three different date like 20+20+60=100).

Now the list which I've created it's strait forward like below :-

Order Date,Purchased Date, Order Qty, Purchased Qty,Balance Qty (calculated),Status(Pending / Completed)

For this particular scenario the Qty was purchased in three lots (three different dates) so not sure how to archive this.

Please advice. Also if you have some link,steps for purchase order please provide

Comment: Create another field which can identify this group order uniquely - Like Order Number

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: Hi Amal, I didn't understand can you provide example please.

Comment: Hi Arsalan, My Question is for Example if order qty = 50 & Deliver Qty = 50 then fine user can enter the purchase date, deliver date,enter the deliver Qty then Balance Qty will show zero in SharePoint List.But if purchased Qty 50 is purchased in three different date like on 8th = 10 Qty, 12th = 20 Qty and 15th = Qty so here I'm not sure how to enter the details in SharePoint List.

Comment: Hi, Any help on this question please.